# append element BEHIND link

Tags: jquery, dom

I try to append a link after another.

this is the dom:

```
<div class='anyclass'><a href="#">1stlink</a></div>
```

I tried

```
$('.anyclass a').append("<a href=\"#\">2ndlink</a>")
```

But this adds the second link INSIDE the caption of the first:

```
<div class='anyclass'><a href="#">1stlink<a href="#">2ndlink</a></a></div>
```

As you might guess I want this instead:

```
<div class='anyclass'><a href="#">1stlink</a><a href="#">2ndlink</a></div>
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/): "The .append() method inserts the specified content **as the last child** of each element in the jQuery collection"

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this is marked "offtopic"? and minus votes? Might not be the most brilliant question, but valid for SO imho. (I am not angry, just surprised)

Comment: @OleAlbers - I didn't flag or downvote this, but I'm guessing others did because you seemed to misunderstand (in the scope of this question) what `append` means.

Comment: @admdrew That guess was close enough. But imho that does not make this a "bad" question

Comment: @OleAlbers - Yeah, I would agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include the `a`in the selector :

```
$('.anyclass').append("<a href=\"#\">2ndlink</a>")
```

or use `.after()`

```
$('.anyclass a').after("<a href=\"#\">2ndlink</a>")
```